# change style of div within a div

Tags: jquery

I want to change below's div style from display: none!important; to display: block!important;

```
<div class="some-class">
  <div style="display: none !important;">
    SOME TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

How to I taget this? I have a code like below:

```
$('.some-class').attr("style", "display: inline !important");
```

Obviously I cannot access the code itself and change anything in it.

Comment: Shouldn't the selector be `$('.some-class > div')`? And after your edit it seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1oranf28/

Comment: thanks. how do I target a div within div? I mean in styles I'd do: 
div.some-class > div

Comment: @MichaelD **EDIT:** I'm now seeing that you edited your post to *correct the code*, thus invalidating the entire question. I'm going to roll this back so that the answers don't get punished.

Comment: @MichaelD Also, "in styles I'd do..." - Note that jQuery selectors and CSS selectors are more or less identical. Any selectors you can do in CSS will more-than-likely work in jQuery, along with some additional selectors that CSS doesn't have available, like `:has()`. `"div.some-class > div"` would do exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try it.

```
$('.some-class').children().attr("style", "display: block !important");
```

Comment: This works for this situation. But why add the `children`? No need to change ALL the elements in the container (if there were more).. Beter use `.find('div:first')` for example.

Comment: @SvenvanZoelen OP themselves suggested a perfectly fine alternative in the comments as well: `"div.some-class > div"`

Comment: @TylerRoper indeed, even better.